# Swift - Issue with using webviews when launch screen images are used instead of launch screen file

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm working on a iOS project and this one issue is bugging me for days. I have a simple webview wrapper in my application and the issue that I'm having is that if I use launch screen images and not the launch screen file the webview content gets badly scaled. I cannot relate why the launch screen images should have any impact on the webview that is being presented later. My goal IS to use the launch screen images.

This is mostly noticeable on iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 plus.

Example with launch screen images:

[image]

Example with launch screen storyboard:

[image]

Any advice is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have you put all the launch images for all  devices in the assets? Also in general tab of your target , have you set the Launch Image Source to Launch Image set of your assets?

Comment: The only missing assets are "iPad Portrait iOS 7-9" but the iPad scaling is fine. The issue is best seen on iPhone 6.

And yes, I did set the assets source in general tab.

Comment: Have you  remove the Launch Story board name from launch screen file option in general tab?

Comment: @Muneeba Yes, I have. That's the only way to use the launch screen images. Otherwise, the storyboard is used.

Comment: Have you applied proper constraint to your web view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is because of the missing launch image for iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 plus. Make sure that you have added all the launch screen images.

Comment: I just noticed that I have more missing images than I expected including the Retina HD 5.5 and 4.7 ones. I'll add the rest and let you know. Thanks